# Can't break while True

Tags: python, python-3.x

First post here!

I know there are few threads like this one, I've read them, but didn't succeed.

Can't break out of while True loop (at the bottom of the code where "break" is) and continue to a sound file. I am new to programming, just learning...

Thanks in advance.

```
# calculating coin price
coinprice = Decimal(binance()) * Decimal(binancecr())
shorted = round(coinprice, 4)
# creating list
highestvalue = [0.0001]
# getting current time
formattime = "%H:%M:%S"
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
now_currenttime = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
# getting current price
print(shorted, "$", "= Starting Price", "(", now_currenttime.strftime(formattime), ")")

while True:
    # getting current time
    formattime = "%H:%M:%S"
    now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
    now_currenttime = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
    # formatting coin price
    deciplaces = Decimal(binance()) * Decimal(binancecr())
    rounded = round(deciplaces, 4)
    # getting highest price
    for item in highestvalue:
        if item < rounded:
            del highestvalue[0]
            highestvalue.append(rounded)
    # printing highest price
    print(highestvalue[0], "$", "= Highest Price ", "(", now_currenttime.strftime(formattime), ")")
    # calculating desired price
    percentage = Decimal(highestvalue[0]) * Decimal(0.001) / Decimal(100)
    percentcalc = Decimal(highestvalue[0]) - Decimal(percentage)
    percconv = Decimal(percentcalc)
    percround = round(percconv, 4)
    # calculating percentage change
    change_percent = ((Decimal(highestvalue[0]) - Decimal(rounded)) / Decimal(rounded)) * Decimal(100.00)
    convchange_percent = Decimal(change_percent)
    roundchange_percent = round(convchange_percent, 4)
    # printing current price, desired price and percentage changes
    print(rounded, "$", "= Current Price ", "(", now_currenttime.strftime(formattime), ")")
    print(percround, "$", "= Desired Price ", "(", now_currenttime.strftime(formattime), ")")
    print(roundchange_percent, "  %", "= Percent Change", "(", now_currenttime.strftime(formattime), ")")
    print("--------------------------------------")
    # checking price drop
    if highestvalue[0] <= percround:
        # when highestvalue[0] goes below percround while True won't break and continue to a sound file
        break
    # time interval in seconds
    time.sleep(3)
# playing sound when coin price reaches desired price
winsound.PlaySound(fname, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Comment: Did you check your if statement is true with `print`?

Comment: That *must* mean that `highestvalue[0] <= percroun` is never true. You're sure about the data? They must be something other than what you're expecting.

Comment: Add `print(repr(highestvalue[0]), repr(percround))` just before the if statement. Are you getting the values you want? `repr` shows the python representation of the data so you can spot the difference between strings and integers.

Comment: Yeah, part of my brain which is dedicated to logic (if any) failed.
Print statement is never true

Comment: @VitaPepe It happens. We all do it. That's why it's important to debug. You won't always be 100% right, so you need to learn to find your mistakes so you can fix them. Just printing the data is the simplest way.